# For some reason vs In some reason

Tags: phrases

What are the differences between:

> **for some reason**

and

> **in some reason**

?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context please?

Comment: The difference is ***for some reason*** is a perfectly ordinary collocation, but the sequence ***in some reason*** [doesn't occur naturally](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+some+reason%2Cin+some+reason&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20some%20reason%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20some%20reason%3B%2Cc0) in ***any*** context in English.

Comment: Put more simply, we don't say 'in some reason'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although rules about prepositions are shot through with exceptions and nuances, "for" generally is associated wuth purpose or benefit whereas "in" generally is associated with place or time or a physical object.

"For some reason" and "for some reason or other" both mean that the purpose is unknown and not obvious. Frequently, there is an implication that the purpose was foolish or odd.

In the phrase, "for some reason," the word "reason" is being used in its meaning of "purpose," and so "for" is the natural preposition to use. In fact, as Michael Harvey said, we simply do not say "in some reason." If you provided us with more context, we could give a better answer because, like FumbleFingers, I cannot imagine a context where you would have heard anything like "in some reason."

**EDIT**: Although I stand by my assertion that generally "in" is associated with time ("in an hour"), a place ("in Paris"), or a physical object ("in the oven"), FumbleFingers is correct that "in" is used in many phrases that cannot even be analogized to any of those three categories. I shall let FumbleFingers find an appropriate designation for this fourth category of usages because I have failed to do so. In any case, "for some reason" is standard English, and "in some reason" is not.

Comment: Re the final paragraph, ***way*** is neither a place nor a time nor a physical object. But [***in some way***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in+some+way%22) is a very common collocation. So that can't be the reason why we don't say ***in some reason*** (or ***for some way***, come to that! :)

Comment: I did say "generally," and "way" does have as its etymological root a place such as a "path" or "passage.". :)

Comment: *In some sense* I guess that makes sense! :)

Comment: I guess I must retreat to "generally." :)

Comment: ***In** general? **In** a way? **In** hindsight?* Incidentally, I did find [this post in *Daily Writing Tips*](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/for-some-reason/) - I first noticed the non-idiomatic phrase “in some reason” used in place of “for some reason” in an email:

In some reason I have not received my order.

***A Web search revealed that this error is widespread***

Comment: OK. You are correct. I have made edits.

Comment: I never disagreed with the *first* paragraph of your answer - just the final bit saying that it's the fact that "**reason**" *is neither a place nor a time nor a physical object* that "explains" why we don't use it with the preposition "**in**". But I think your edit making the link between "**reason**" and "**purpose**" pretty much nails the question of why we ***do*** use "**for**" (so we don't use "**in**" because we ***do*** use "**for**").

Comment: No I understood exactly why you were disagreeing. It just took a while to convince me.